Custom proxy creation with spring boot - Headers and RequestParam issues
As instructed by my boss, I'm trying to create a proxy that receives a URL and a request (method, header, body) and correctly routes the request to the endpoint provided and returns the response. Simple, right? Yeah, not really.
An example, using postman, we can enter 'GET' http://localhost:8080/proxy/router?url=https://paste.rs/nvrD8. It should make a GET request to the url: "https://paste.rs/nvrD8" and in the same vein, a 'POST' http://paste.rs/ with a body, should do similarly.
The issue one now is - I keep getting encoded characters from my 'GET' response body. I mean, characters like these: "WY��{���Z�]ëD". POST and PUT requests give me "I/O error on POST request for "https://paste.rs/nvrD8": insufficient data written". But they work when I remove the @RequestHeader (and prevent the user from sending headers) but we want the user to be able to send users.
Issue two is, when I try to call a 'GET' on http://localhost:8080/proxy/router?url=https://login.money.net/money/example/api/ipg/v1/recon/api/remita/txn-proc-requests-report?page=0&size=20&sort=id&isAdmin=true&compId=011, only "https://login.money.net/money/example/api/ipg/v1/recon/api/remita/txn-proc-requests-report?page=0" gets sent to the backend meaning it omits some parts of the URL somehow.
Please help! As my job largely depends on it. Here is my code:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/proxy")
public class ProxyController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProxyController.class);

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @RequestMapping("/router")
    public ResponseEntity<?> routeRequest(
            @RequestParam String url,
            @RequestBody(required = false) Map<String, Object> body,
            @RequestHeader Map<String, String> headers,
            HttpServletRequest request
    ) {
        HttpMethod method = HttpMethod.valueOf(request.getMethod().toUpperCase());

        try {
            HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.forEach(requestHeaders::set);

            // Ensure Content-Type is set for POST and PUT
            if (method == HttpMethod.POST || method == HttpMethod.PUT) {
                requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            }

            HttpEntity<?> requestEntity;
            if (method == HttpMethod.GET || method == HttpMethod.DELETE) {
                requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(requestHeaders);
            } else if (body != null) {
                requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(body, requestHeaders);
            } else {
                requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(requestHeaders);
            }

            logger.info("Sending {} request to URL: {}", method, url);
            logger.info("Headers: {}", requestHeaders);
            logger.info("Body: {}", body);

            ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, method, requestEntity, String.class);

            logger.info("Received response with status: {}", response.getStatusCode());
            logger.info("Response body: {}", response.getBody());

            // Ensure the response body is correctly interpreted as a string
            return new ResponseEntity<>(response.getBody(), response.getStatusCode());
        } catch (HttpStatusCodeException ex) {
            logger.error("HttpStatusCodeException: {}", ex.getResponseBodyAsString(), ex);
            return ResponseEntity.status(ex.getStatusCode()).body(ex.getResponseBodyAsString());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Exception: ", ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Internal Server Error");
        }
    }
}

I have put logs in the code and it should work generally, I don't know what else to do. I also tried encoding the URL and decoding it - It didn't work. I have desperately searched online for resources, but it seems like I'm the only one has ever tried this. I know for sure it's mainly a header and RequestParam problem.

Why are you writing your own proxy? Use Spring Cloud Gateway which already has this solved or something like NGINX which does all of this for you. Don't reinvented the wheel.

Apparently, it seems like trying to do this is a waste of time but I did solve it actually. To fix the url issue, I just made the user pass it in the header to get it as a whole and to fix the header issue, the problem was that the header properties 'content-length' and 'host' that was being sent to my proxy was being forwarded directly in the request to the original url so I had to exclude these properties from the header. Lastly, I had to make the response a byte[] datatype to handle various response types (html, json, xml, etc.)
Here is my updated code:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/proxy")
public class testProxyController {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(testProxyController.class);

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @RequestMapping("/router/")
    public ResponseEntity<?> routeRequest(
            @RequestHeader Map<String, String> header,
            @RequestBody(required = false) Map<String, Object> body,
            HttpServletRequest request
    ) {
        String url = header.get("url");
        if (url == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Missing URL in headers");
        }

        HttpMethod method = HttpMethod.valueOf(request.getMethod().toUpperCase());

        try {
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            header.remove("url");

            header.forEach((key, value) -> {
                if (!key.equalsIgnoreCase(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH) && !key.equalsIgnoreCase(HttpHeaders.HOST)) {
                    headers.set(key, value);
                }
            });

            HttpEntity<?> requestEntity;
            if (method == HttpMethod.GET || method == HttpMethod.DELETE) {
                requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
            } else if (body != null) {
                requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);
            } else {
                requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);
            }

            ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, method, requestEntity, byte[].class);

            HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
            response.getHeaders().forEach((key, value) -> {
                if (!key.equalsIgnoreCase(HttpHeaders.TRANSFER_ENCODING)) {
                    responseHeaders.put(key, value);
                }
            });

            return new ResponseEntity<>(response.getBody(), responseHeaders, response.getStatusCode());
        } catch (HttpStatusCodeException ex) {
            logger.error("HttpStatusCodeException: {}", ex.getResponseBodyAsString(), ex);
            return 
ResponseEntity.status(ex.getStatusCode()).body(ex.getResponseBodyAsString());
        }
    }
}

